# Find basis of subspace in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having some problems finding the basis of a subspace $W$ of the vector space $\mathbb{C}^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Let us say that $W$ is generated by the vectors in $S=\{(i,1),(1,1),(-1,0),(0,i)\}$, how would I go about finding the basis of $W$? Since $\dim{\mathbb{C}^2}=2$, I know that the basis of $W$ cannot be larger than $2$ so the vectors in $S$ are necessarily linearly dependent. I appreciate any help in this question :D

Comment: Take a random vector of your generating family, then find a second vector that is linearly independent from the first. If it's not possible, then the dimension is 1  and the process stops here otherwise the dimension is 2. Then choose a third vector independent from the two first. If not possible then the two first vectors are your basis and the dimension is 2. Otherwise continue with 3. Repeat the process etc...

Comment: @Lelouch Thank you for your answer! So in this case, would {(i,1),(-1,0)} be a basis and the dimension would be 2? 

I also have another question. Isn't this possible to by using gauss-elimination on a matrix of the vectors? I think I have seen a similar method before.